# How to make a POST request with file content via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to make a post call with powershell which should contain the file content as body, so I try to use Invoke-Webrequest.
When I make the call like this, there is no data on the server side. I can see that on the server where the HttpServletRequest.getInputStream is null, any idea what is the problem?

```
$FilePath = '.\foobar.txt'

$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Encoding Byte
Write-host $fileContent
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Body $fileContent -Method 'POST' -Uri 'http://myAddress'
```

Comment: [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) has an `-InFile` parameter.

Comment: Also consider `Invoke-RestMethod` if your server expects `multipart/form-data` rather than raw binary content.

Comment: I tried it alread with the -InFile but it also results in an error, that on the server side the getInputstream is null

Comment: found my problem, it was required to set the application header to content-type to application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

tldr: You need to add the Parameter `-ContentType "application/octet-stream"`

First of all you should replace `Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Encoding Byte` with `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)` as it is way faster. This is also the reason why I do not suggest to use the `-InFile` Parameter as it internaly also uses that slow, inperformant `Get-Content` Method.

In combination you propably also need to add `-ContentType "application/octet-stream"` otherwise the Body is not serialised as the raw byte array.

So in the end it should look something like this:

```
$FilePath = '.\foobar.txt'
$fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Body $fileContent -Method 'POST' -Uri 'http://myAddress' -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'
```